# Why am I seeing a distorted boundary forming upon depositing a drop of 70% IPA on the surface of oil in a petri dish instead of a clear one?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

I was trying to examine the effects of varying the concentrations of IPA droplets dyed with methylene blue on the phenomenon observed when they are deposited on an oil surface. I believe it is called Marangoni bursting, and up to 55% I was getting results that looked like what I had seen on demos online[image]

However, for concentrations 60% and above, I got formations that looked like this

[image]
I am not sure as to what may have caused this, and it occurred even after repeated retrials. Please explain to me what it might be. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your experimental setup is being affected by alcohol evaporation and recondensation on the droplet surface, which will vary in interesting ways as the water-to-alcohol proportion is varied.

Since the evaporation and recondensation processes are occurring not in the bulk of the droplet but at its exposed surface, the composition of the mix at the surface is not going to be the same as that in the bulk which means that funny business will occur at that "skin" that you wouldn't ordinarily expect- and that the moisture and alcohol content of the nearby air will play an interesting role as well.

This is a fascinating business and I encourage you to read up on the marangoni effect, viscous fingering,  colligative properties of solutions including vapor pressure depression versus alcohol content in water, and rayleigh instability.